# Testing Script - Find open MySQL Ports and check Database

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, perl, security

following Problem:

I want to Check all Open MySQL Ports in a network and give myself a list of them.

- After this i want to check if i can get access to the MySQL database from the open ports.

It Would be just a security check script to avoid other people getting access to the databases.

Bash/perl/Powershell... maybe someone can give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [NMAP](https://nmap.org/) for all port scanning tasks.

**EDIT:**

Lets asssume an example: mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122(This vulnerability tries to access the MySql server through open ports by bypassing authentication, if possible, also dumps the MySQL usernames and password hashes.)

Pre-requisite: You need the '[Vulns](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/lib/vulns.html)' library to be installed separately. Please read the documentation, to know more about how to install and other details, since it would be too tedious to explain it here.

```
mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122.pass
MySQL password. Default: nmapFTW.

mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122.user
MySQL username. Default: root.

mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122.iterations
Connection retries. Default: 1500.

mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122.socket_timeout
Socket timeout. Default: 5s.
```

Please leave the password blank to check for non-password vulnerabilities.

Command to run:

```
nmap -p3306 --script mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122 <target>
```

Here  is your MySql instance

This will give an output, something like this:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE REASON
3306/tcp open  mysql   syn-ack
mysql-vuln-cve2012-2122:
VULNERABLE:
Authentication bypass in MySQL servers.
State: VULNERABLE
 IDs:  CVE:CVE-2012-2122
  Description:
    When a user connects to MariaDB/MySQL, a token (SHA
    over a password and a random scramble string) is calculated and 
compared
    with the expected value. Because of incorrect casting, it might've
    happened that the token and the expected value were considered 
equal,
    even if the memcmp() returned a non-zero value. In this case
   MySQL/MariaDB would think that the password is correct, even while 
it is
    not.  Because the protocol uses random strings, the probability of
    hitting this bug is about 1/256.
    Which means, if one knows a user name to connect (and "root" 
almost
    always exists), she can connect using *any* password by repeating
    connection attempts. ~300 attempts takes only a fraction of 
second, so
    basically account password protection is as good as nonexistent.

  Disclosure date: 2012-06-9
  Extra information:
  Server granted access at iteration #204
  root:*9CFBBC772F3F6C106020035386DA5BBBF1249A11
  debian-sys-maint:*BDA9386EE35F7F326239844C185B01E3912749BF
  phpmyadmin:*9CFBBC772F3F6C106020035386DA5BBBF1249A11
```

For more and detailed info, please refer the above link.

The NMAP tools will not only help you in getting the list of port related vulnerabilities. It can also be used to search for other vulnerabilities like MySql injection,DDOS, brute force vulnerabilities and lot more. Though you need to download separate libraries for those.

Comment: This is a bit short for an answer. It's not really a comment either though. I suggest you [edit] and include some examples, even if it's just a quote of the doc synopsis, and an explanation of why it's a useful tool.